# unity development - retrieve device data, permissions?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

While developing apps for android in android studio, I had to mark permissions in the manifest file, and then use and ask for the persmissions in some other files.

how is that working with the unity engine?

can I write some c# code in order to get the device phone number, or contacts list? if so, how is it possible? where do I need to register permissions, in order to use it and to make sure it will be ok with google play restrictions later on?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the default `AndroidManifest.xml` on `<YourUnityInstallationDirectory>/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/androidplayer/AndroidManifest.xml`.

If you want to modify it, copy it to `/Assets/Plugins/Android` (create the folder if it doesn't exist) and then modify your copy.

Comment: I've searched through the whole installation dir of my unity for a AndroidManifest.xml but it didn't find anything. any suggestions? (and I do have android sdk installed, because I can test my unity game on my android device).

Comment: Are you using a Windows or a Mac machine?

Comment: woops... sorry, it was inside this: androidplayer/APK/ <- in here. now I need to copy and paste it to where exactly? somewhere in my project?

Comment: Yes, you have to copy it to `/Assets/Plugins/Android` on your project. Unity should use it instead of the default one when you generate your apk

Comment: understood. and if I don't have even a plugin folder, create it? thank you

Comment: Yes, you need to create the `Plugins` folder and the `Android` folder if you don't have them in your project

Comment: after adding the manifest files, how do I retrieve the data durin an onLoad action of the game for example? I know how to do it in android studio, but in unity I don't know how to start